# I have problems when doing "yarn start" after applying tailwindcss to my react application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, tailwind-css

I have a problem when applying **tailwindcss** with **postcss** to my React Application (which was created using `create-react-app`)

I was change `scripts` in **package.json**, here is my **package.json** now look like:

```
{
  "name": "octopus-one",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "postcss src/styles/index.tailwind.css -o src/styles/index.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/styles/index.tailwind.css -o src/styles/index.css -w",
    "start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.4.6"
  }
}
```

after that, I run the `yarn start`. but this is all I got:

> C:\Dev\octopus-one>yarn start 
>   yarn run v1.21.1 
>   $ npm run watch:css && react-scripts start 
>  
>   octopus-one@0.1.0 watch:css C:\Dev\octopus-one 
>   postcss src/styles/index.tailwind.css -o src/styles/index.css -w 
>  
>   _

development server default `create-react-app` does not running.

everything is fine, no errors whatsoever. it's just like it looks like a `npm run watch:css` always running and 
`react-scripts start` doesn't running. 

it looks like I made a mistake in `package.json` but I don't know what I should do.

I just wanna `react-scripts start` running after completing `npm run watch:css`, 
so that I can access the development server as usual ( in localhost: 3000).

I still new for **react** and this is first time I use **tailwindcss** for my react application. 
hope you can help, 
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I was able to solve this problem and I will answer my own question above.

I use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run more than one command at a time.

so i installed:

> yarn add concurrently -D

then I change `script` in my **package.json** to this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build:css": "postcss src/styles/index.tailwind.css -o src/styles/index.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/styles/index.tailwind.css -o src/styles/index.css -w",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run watch:css\" \"react-scripts start\"",
    "build": "concurrently  \"npm run build:css\" \"react-scripts build\"",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

and finally I can run `npm run watch:css` before running `react-scripts start`

Comment: I had the same issue, thank you for posting your solution. Every setup video I have seen no one goes over this. I don't know how they are not having the same issues.